# How to DRY an RSpec code that tests similar methods of the same class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have such a code:

```
RSpec.describe CypherFileExecution do
  describe "self.drop_data_and_execute" do
    # (...)
    it "drops old data" do
      # (...)
    end
    it "executes cypher file" do
      described_class.drop_data_and_execute('spec/seeds/neo4j_object_spec.cypher')
      expect([
        does_object_exist_in_db?("relationship-class"),
        does_object_exist_in_db?("class-instance-class"),        
      ]).to eql [true, true]
    end
  end
  describe "self.execute" do
    it "executes cypher file" do
      described_class.execute('spec/seeds/neo4j_object_spec.cypher')
      expect([
        does_object_exist_in_db?("relationship-class"),
        does_object_exist_in_db?("class-instance-class"),        
      ]).to eql [true, true]
    end
  end
end
```

As we can see, the `"executes cypher file"` blocks are the same for both methods (in fact, one of them calls another one). What can I do to make this code DRY? If I'm not mistaken, shared examples and contexts work at the class level, but I have the method level here. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a use case for [shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples), which we can use in conjonction with `subject`, leveraging RSpec's lazy evaluation.

```rb
RSpec.describe CypherFileExecution do
  shared_examples 'executes cypher file' do
    it "executes cypher file" do
      subject
      expect(does_object_exist_in_db?("relationship-class")).to be(true)
      expect(does_object_exist_in_db?("class-instance-class")).to be(true)
    end
  end

  describe "self.drop_data_and_execute" do
    subject { described_class.drop_data_and_execute('spec/seeds/neo4j_object_spec.cypher') }
    include_examples 'executes cypher file'

    # (...)
    it "drops old data" do
      # (...)
    end
  end

  describe "self.execute" do
    subject { described_class.execute('spec/seeds/neo4j_object_spec.cypher') }
    include_examples 'executes cypher file'
  end
end
```

Comment: This could be further improved by using two separate expectations instead of ´expect([...]).to eql [true, true]´ which will give a very cryptic and unhelpful failure message. I would also use a block passed to shared examples for the setup instead of abusing subject.

Comment: By abusing subject i mean that it should be used to provide the subject under test. What you are doing is just using it for side effects

Comment: I concurr, that would remove the dependency on `subject`. Force of habit, I guess it's fine if there's a team convention, like mine, that `subject` refers to a call of a method, not the object tested (if any). Another option would be `before { setup }`, and remove `subject` from the shared example.